# ERROR : The specified DSN contains anarchitecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, odbc, business-intelligence

. I try to connect my BI project in visual studio 2008 to mysql database. so I defined odbc connection in Start > Programs > Administrative Tools > Data Sources [win 7] and I tasted it, it connected successfully .

but when I want to open this connection in VS > "View" > "Server Explorer", I see this error:

> ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN
>   contains anarchitecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

[image]

even I put "root" as user name in the text box and pass empty [bc I didn`t set pass for my mysql db] , but nothing changed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you use the 64-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or remove a DSN that connects to a 32-bit driver, for example, Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb), you will receive the following error message:

The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

To resolve this error, use the 32-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or remove the DSN.

Comment: Please provide a summary of the information at the link you provided in case the link breaks in the future.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: The link provided is an awesome resource! Turns out there are TWO, freaking TWO, completely different versions of the ODBC Administrator, one that apparently doesn't work with 64-bit systems, but for some reason is the default, and then the other one, buried in Windows/SysWOW64/. God dammit Microsoft!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but with a console application in Visual Studio 2008. The project's Platform Target was set to "Any CPU" which defaulted to 64 bit, and when I tried to access data using a 32bit ODBC driver I got the error described by @afsane. My solution was to set the Platform Target to x86:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this problem but the reconfiguring of the access driver to 32 bit did not solve it.

I was running a .vbs script from the task scheduler. It gave me the 800004005 Error architecture mismatch error.

I was running the 64 bit Windows Scripting host instead of the 32 bit version. As soon a I specifed the 32 bit WSH the code worked like it did on my Win 2000 server. No errors