# Extracting Excel data using Sql connection string

Tags: sql

My intention here is to render the excel data in a table, using a datatable, so opened an odbc connection and loaded the datatable like this:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};Driverid=790;Dbq=C:\Users\*******\Documents\Book1.xlsx;DefaultDir=C:\Users\******\Documents;HDR=YES);
conn.Open();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
string con = "select * from [sheet1$]";
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand cmd = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand(con, conn);
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dataTable.Load(dr);
```

But insted getting an error like this

> ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

So actually whats' the root cause ?

Comment: Are there some quotes missing from your code? Is it C#?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365146/error-the-specified-dsn-contains-anarchitecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-an

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following link as a possible solution to your problem:

[ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application](http://dacosta9.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/error-im014-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application/)

Comment: now everything fine , but when I establish a connection with same connection string above , I got this error "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified "

Comment: I got the way , yes I was using the DSN which was not found in the ODBC server , so I created the DSN and then utilized it .

Comment: Great, glad I could assist!

Comment: Creating a **x86 Excel DSN** worked for me. Used **ODBC Admin** to create new *"Excel Files x86"* DSN. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8f008fab-55f5-4636-80f5-228f6a31feee/acquireconnection-method-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application) suggests

```
"changing the Platform target project setting from Any CPU to x86."
```

will help. The root cause is, as the error says, a mismatch between the database driver and your application.

[These docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say

> If you use the 64-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or remove a DSN that
>   connects to a 32-bit driver, for example, Driver do Microsoft Access
>   (*.mdb), you will receive the following error message: The specified
>   DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and
>   Application To resolve this error, use the 32-bit odbcad32.exe to
>   configure or remove the DSN.